# WP FullCalendar Image Thumbs on Full Calendar

Tags: calendar

I’m trying to get WP FullCalendar to display the Event thumbnail in the associated cell on the Calendar. The #_EVENTIMAGE code works fine in the regular calendar, but when entering the shortcode into the "Event Title Format" under "Full Calendar Options" under General tab, the thumbnail just displays as the HTML and not the actual image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: is there a way to display the Eventimage within the full calendar? I tried the #_EVENTIMAGE but that doesnt work.Tahnks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the Event thumbnail in the associated cell on the Calendar, we can do without using the 'WP FullCalendar' as follows.

1. First of all deactivate 'WP Full Calendar' (if already activated)
2. To add the formatting we want, go to Events > Settings > Formatting > Calendar and add this code:

   #_EVENTIMAGE